# How do I see which user that invoked a Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, aws-iot

Need some help with Lambda invocation and authentication. I have an AWS Lambda function that is invoked from AWS IoT MQTT feed based on a specific topic. The invocation happens when an authenticated IoT Thing publishes to MQTT on that topic. My question is how do I see who has invoked it? I need this information so I know under what user to store the published information to database. I'm guessing there should be some environment variables that carry this information but I haven't found it. Maybe I been looking in all the wrong places:/

Many thanks,
Marcus

Comment: It's definitely not in an environment variable. You need to push the user info as part of the MQTT message, which will make it available in the `event` object inside the Lambda function. How is the user/thing authenticating exactly?

Comment: Hi Mark, sorry i realize i didn't mention the authentication. I use the X.509. So AWS IoT should(if I understand correctly) know exactly what thing that published to the MQTT since the certificate is unique to that Thing. I was hoping to use that to identify the sender. But of course the sender could send his user /pw authentication as part of MQTT. I was just hoping to do away with password handling since there is already certificate based authentication being done. Maybe i have misunderstood the possibilities of use that mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to modify the Lambda trigger in your IoT configuration to include the [client ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-sql-function-clientid) by using something like the following SQL statement:

```
select clientId() as clientId, *
```

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks, that worked well. I can then also restrict the clientId to a specific thing and together i think that should let me know with certainty who the post came from. Many thanks!

I added the below to the IoT Rule
`SELECT *, clientid() as clientid FROM 'topic'`

Answer (score 0):

How are you?

You could send the user on the topic message. Is it not easier? Not sure how to get it from env var.

Comment: Hi Leandro, that would be possible, just i was hoping to do away with user/pw and rely on the X.509 certificate authentication that's done as part of AWS IoT whenever a thing publishes to a topic. But I have to admit I don't fully grasp all the aspects of that feature.